# i keep getting attribute error randint

Tags: python, python-3.x

everytime I run my code I get attribute error and int has no randint, but when I looked online how to do random, that is what it told me to do, please help.

```
def gorandom():
        if random.randint(1,8) == 1:
            turtle.goto(-250,250)
        elif random.randint(1,8) == 2:
            turtle.goto(0,250)
        elif random.randint(1,8) == 3:
            turtle.goto(250,250)
        elif random.randint(1,8) == 4:
            turtle.goto(250,0)
        elif random.randint(1,8) == 5:
            turtle.goto(250,-250)
        elif random.randint(1,8) == 6:
            turtle.goto(0,-250)
        elif random.randint(1,8) == 7:
            turtle.goto(-250,-250)
        else:
            turtle.goto(-250,0)
```

Comment: didn't you call your module `random.py` by chance?

Comment: @WasteD wouldnt it be `from random import *`? and Gurneyguy you probably havent imported the `random` module to your script

Comment: @WasteD I did, I still get the error...

Comment: Can you add your error message?

Comment: You probably assigned an integer value to the global name `random`, independent of whether you imported `random` or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an import. Please add

```
import random
```

To the top of your file.

Comment: No, that would result in `NameError: name 'random' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import random

def gorandom():
    if random.randint(1,8) == 1:
        turtle.goto(-250,250)
    elif random.randint(1,8) == 2:
        turtle.goto(0,250)
    elif random.randint(1,8) == 3:
        turtle.goto(250,250)
    elif random.randint(1,8) == 4:
        turtle.goto(250,0)
    elif random.randint(1,8) == 5:
        turtle.goto(250,-250)
    elif random.randint(1,8) == 6:
        turtle.goto(0,-250)
    elif random.randint(1,8) == 7:
        turtle.goto(-250,-250)
    else:
        turtle.goto(-250,0)
```

And be sure your goto(x,y) function works ;)

Comment: line 10, in gorandom
    if random.randint(1,8) == 1:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'

Comment: and this near the top of the error: return self.func(*args)

Answer (score 0):

found solution, thanks guys for help

```
from random import randint

def gorandom():
        if randint(1,8) == 1:
           turtle.goto(-250,250)
        elif randint(1,8) == 2:
            turtle.goto(0,250)
        elif randint(1,8) == 3:
            turtle.goto(250,250)
        elif randint(1,8) == 4:
            turtle.goto(250,0)
        elif randint(1,8) == 5:
            turtle.goto(250,-250)
        elif randint(1,8) == 6:
            turtle.goto(0,-250)
        elif randint(1,8) == 7:
            turtle.goto(-250,-250)
        else:
            turtle.goto(-250,0)
```

Comment: Each of those `if` and `elif` lines is generating a different random number. You're not throwing a single 8-sided die and choosing where to go based on the die roll; you're throwing the die over and over again.